# VeraCrypt volumes get unmounted after sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, veracrypt

Good day everyone!

I've recently upgraded to **Ubuntu-Mate Bionic 18.04** and now fighting new "features". Google has helped a lot, but this time I didn't manage to find a solution.

Every time I resume from sleep, VeraCrypt process dissapears and the previously mounted encrypted volume gets unmounted with no visible error messages. It's a simple file container located on main SSD, not on external drive.

I've used to put my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 to sleep having a VeraCrypt volume mounted and had no issues after resume until swithcing to 18.04. It always resumed with VeraCrypt still running and the volume mounted. Now it's a clean install of Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 with all partitions reformatted, not just a dist-upgrade and this version has such issue.

This issue is terribly annoying as I can't use sleep mode because of it. First time it even lead to data loss as the volume just dissapeared despite it's been in use by a running program.

Will appreciate any advice on how to debug this. I can't even figure out if it happens while going to sleep or while resuming and, what is the most important, **why** does this happen.

Thank you!

Comment: I would think that unmounting after wake from sleep is a good security measure. Otherwise what's the point

Comment: Security is in how and when you use sleep mode. It would be great to disable this "feature" :) It wasn't present in any of previous Ubuntu or Mint versions I had used before and that was great.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found a solution myself.

To prevent VeraCrypt from unmounting volumes on sleep\suspend edit the file

```
/etc/default/veracrypt
```

And change line

```
VERACRYPT_SUSPEND_UNMOUNT="yes"
```

To

```
VERACRYPT_SUSPEND_UNMOUNT="no"
```

Changes take effect immediately after saving the file. No need to reboot nor restart any services.